# Heroku Kafka certificates

Tags: heroku, certificate, apache-kafka

According to the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/kafka-on-heroku), Heroku passes KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT, KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT and KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY directly into my heroku applications. In consequence, only applications running on heroku can access Heroku Kafka? I would like to access it directly from my home workstation but i dont know how to get the ENVs

Answer (score 0):

You can run either `heroku config --app your_application_name` to get all variables, or run `heroku config:get KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT --app your_application_name` to just get one specific variable.

You can also login to Heroku dashboard and find all variables there in "Settings" section of your app.

Comment: Ah, youre right! I just forgot about this option. Do you know if that is recommended? If heroku changes these vars regularly, i would always have to get new values manually. And do you know if heroku allows access to kafka clusters from the internet or just from heroku apps?